# Java crossword solver

Tags: java, regex, data-structures

I need to construct a method that for a string such as "s***p*" it finds all possible words from a list of dictionary words that fit that format, where * is any possible letter. I'm trying to do this in minimal time, so I'm trying to decide what structure I need to use to store the data. Any ideas out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use Regex (check this [tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)) for that, it will solve your problem really fast.

Comment: Running a regex over each possible word? That will be pretty slow (possibly even slower than some native checking). Also, if you're going to post an answer, you should probably answer the question rather than just pointing the user to a tutorial (otherwise you should probably just post a comment instead).

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the *'s in your search with a . you can use it as a regex, to compare with strings to find potential matches.

Your real problem is going to be the efficiency of it. Depending on how big your library is, if you check EVERY word, it will takes ages. You could do various things to speed this up though. such as storing words based on their length/starting characters etc.